# What is the distribution followed by this function of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference

$X$ and $Y$ are independently distributed $U(0,1)$ random variables (Uniform distribution)

Find the Variance of the random variable

$U = \dfrac{\ln(X)}{( \ln(X)+\ln(1-Y) )}$

---

I know $-\ln(X)$ follows $\exp(1)$ and $(1-Y)$ is also $U(0,1)$
Therefore it becomes $\exp(1)$ in the numerator and $\text{gamma}(1,2)$ in the denominator. 
I dont know what to do next.

Comment: You wrote "and $\ln(1-Y)$ is also $U(0,1)$.  But this is not true.  Write your  ratio as $S/(S+T)$ where $S,T$ are iid exponential rvs.

Comment: @kimchilover - presumably "and also $-\ln(1-Y) \sim \exp(1)$" or something similar was intended

Comment: @Henry I agree.

Comment: @kimchilover My bad I'm sorry. I've corrected it^

Comment: Good. Did you see the other part of my comment?

Comment: @kimchilover yes I'm trying that. But I dont know how it is going to help me finding the variance

Comment: You will see $U$ has a standard distribution if you derive it (say, by a change of variables or using well-known relations between distributions), from which the variance follows immediately.

Comment: @StubbornAtom which standard distribution? I'm sorry that's what I'm trying on doing.

Comment: @Vishesh You are not showing your work/attempts, so it's hard to know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as 
$$
U=\frac{-\ln X}{-\ln X-\ln (1-Y)}
$$
As you noted $-\ln X\sim \exp(1)$ and because $1-Y\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ it folows that $-\ln(1-Y)\sim \exp(1)$. Since $-\ln X$ and $-\ln (1-Y)$ are independent it follows that $U\sim \text{Beta}(1,1)$ which is the same as a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$.

Comment: I was stuck on this for so long. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @VisheshChugh Sorry but if you were stuck before, you should still be stuck since this answer does not show you how to prove the result but merely invokes a more general fact (which you probably do not know how to prove either) to deduce this one. Strange world...

Comment: @Did There's a thing known as confusion and that shouldn't be so hard for you to understand as you so much already. Don't know why you'd be so irrelevant. Strange world. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

$G(\lambda)=e^{-x}x^{\lambda-1};x>0,\lambda>0 $ and $B_1(u,v)={x^{u-1}}(1-x)^{v-1} ; 0<x<1 ,u>0,v>0 $

$X \sim G(\lambda) $ and $Y\sim G(m)$

$\dfrac{X}{X+Y} \sim B_1(\lambda,m)$

And good luck for JAM $2019$

Comment: Thanks mate. Haha how do you know? You taking it too? This year?

Comment: This question came in any previous year, I solved it few days back!